# MySQL Openrowset (BULK ) gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM master.initial;

INSERT master.initial (IDSUBJECT ,IDTEACHER , Initial)
SELECT '1', '1', Initial. *
FROM OPENROWSET
(BULK 'C:\docs\diplom\data.docx', SINGLE_BLOB)  Initial;
```

This code gives me this syntax error. Where is the problem?
[image]

this is where i took the source code
https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/sql/sqlserver/export-documents-saved-as-blob-binary-from-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET is a feature of Microsoft SQL Server, and it isn't supported in other implementations of SQL, such as MySQL. Please understand that every brand of SQL database has its own enhancements and features. Usually the vendors of these software products make little effort to remain compatible with their competitors.

The closest equivalent function in MySQL is the [LOAD_FILE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).

Using it would look something like this:

```
INSERT master.initial (IDSUBJECT ,IDTEACHER , Initial)
SELECT '1', '1', LOAD_FILE('C:/docs/diplom/data.docx');
```

Read the documentation at the link I gave for more details.